# Отследить закрытие Form2 и если она закрылась то передать глобальную переменную в textBox Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

Отследить закрытие Form2 и если она закрылась то передать глобальную переменную в textBox Form1 ?

Comment: В C# нет глобальных переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Пока писал вопрос - нашел ответ

```
form2.FormClosed += (object s, FormClosedEventArgs args) =>
            {
               textBox3.Text =Data.Value;
            };
```

Comment: Дам вам пару советов: 1. Не обязательно в лямбде писать тип, напишите просто имя аргумента, этого достаточно. 2. Если в теле всего 1 действие, то скобки можно убрать. То есть ваш код можно написать просто: `form2.FormClosed += (s, e) => textBox3.Text = Data.Value;`. Согласитесь, куда приятней выглядит. Короче, советую вам стараться писать легко, просто, красиво и понятно для других. Удачи!